# Cómo realizar aggregate+populate con Mongoose (recibo un error)

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

Les agradezco un poco de ayuda. Estoy realizando una api rest con express y mongodb (v3.4.4), usando mongoose (v4.10.5). Necesito hacer una operación de agregación, pero no doy con ello. Les muestro algo de código. Los modelos (tienen más propiedades, pero lo he dejado lo más simple):

```
const CategoryModel = mongoose.model('Category', new Schema({
    slug: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, index: true },
    description: String
}));

const MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', new Schema({
    category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    other: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Other' }], 
    times_count: { type: Number, default: 0 }
}));
```

Importante, estoy interesado en popular el campo `category` de `MyModel`, no el campo `other`.

Supongamos que `Category` y `MyModel` tiene registros bien formados. La consulta:

```
MyModel.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
      _id : '$_id',
      times: { $sum: '$times_count' }
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 5
  }
]).limit(5).exec().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

`data` es correcto, tiene 5 registros, pero no incluye `category`. Ahora pruebo con:

```
MyModel.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
      _id : '$_id',
      times: { $sum: '$times_count' }
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 5
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Category', // He probado con 'Categories' y 'categories'
      localField: 'category',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'category'
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$category'
  }
]).limit(5).exec().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Y ahora `data` viene vacío, He puesto `mongoose.set('debug', true);` y las operaciones parecen correctas, incluida la última de `aggregate`, pero `data` viene vacío.

No sé si me he explicado bien. Obviamente hay algo que no estoy entendiendo del todo. Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo por si a alguien le viniese bien. [Me ha ayudado el compañero @Mikey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822643/8496784) (en inglés). Aparte este buen hombre me ayudó con otro error que me daba al principio, que me pedía hacer un cursor y era porque estaba usando [Mockgoose](https://github.com/mockgoose/mockgoose) en vez de Mongoose+Mongodb limpio. Por si a alguien le interesa, [aquí](https://github.com/Mockgoose/Mockgoose/issues/32) se está pidiendo la issue sobre el tema del cursor de Mockgoose.

Al lio, el problema es que no estaba incluyendo el campo `category` en la agrupación inicial, hacía falta esto:

```
MyModel.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : '$_id',
            times: { $sum: '$times_count' },
            category: { $first: '$category' }
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 5
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'categories',
            localField: 'category',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'category'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$category'
    }
]).exec(...);
```

Y asunto arreglado ;)